# NodeJs - FTP not working: "npm-shrinkwrap.json is not provided"

Tags: javascript, node.js, ftp

I have got a Nodejs app on [AppFog](http://www.appfog.com/) and want to connect to a ftp-server with [this](https://github.com/mscdex/node-ftp).
I did install it with `npm install ftp` using "Ruby Command Prompt"

This is the only code line:

`var FTPClient = require('ftp');`

Trying to start the app, it throws an error:

`Skipping npm-support: npm-shrinkwrap.json is not provided`

Which kind of server should I use or what's the problem?

Still doesn't start:

```
Starting Application 'test007': .
Error: Application [test007] failed to start, logs information below.
====> /logs/staging.log <====

# Logfile created on 2013-03-09 10:37:09 +0000 by logger.rb/25413
Installing dependencies. Node version 0.8.14
Installing ftp@0.2.9 from local path
Installing xregexp@2.0.0 from local path
Installing node@0.0.0 from local path
Installing nodejs@0.0.1 from local path
```

But no error is shown.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What version of node and npm are you using?  You can check with `npm --version` and `node --version`.  Also, what operating system are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The quick fix is to type `npm shrinkwrap`, which will provide an npm-shrinkwrap file.

A shrinkwrap file fixes the exact versions of your dependencies, and the exact version of their dependencies, and so on.  Without it, each usage of `npm install` could install different versions of the packages -- sometimes, just different bugfix versions (1.4.2 vs 1.4.3), but sometimes much greater differences.  There's no guarantee that your code will work with different dependency versions (in fact it is not uncommon to break), so shrinkwrapping is a great idea for any production-level code.

If you want to 'unshrinkwrap', just delete the `npm-shrinkwrap.json`.  You can re-shrinkwrap at any point.

Comment: Thank you, it now created a shrinkwrap file, but it still failed to start for another reason (edited question)

Comment: You should probably close/accept this question, and then ask another question for the next, different problem.